# Tumblr posts not appearing as search results?

Tags: tumblr

So I am getting a bit confused with tumblr and cant seem to find answers anywhere.

So I signed up for tumblr a week or two ago, made some posts, reblogged some other posts, like and followed stuff. Then I find none of my posts appear in search results.

Say I posted an image of a me wearing a sugar loaf helmet and tag it sugarloaf helmet. Not going to be many results for a tag like that is there? So I go to search, no results. I try logging out and then searching, no results. Try it from a private browser window and from a someone elses computer, trying to eliminate the possibility of tumblr ignoring your own post.

So I search and find vague references to anti-spam systems and new account restrictions.

The problem is there is no details on what is needed to be done to stop being seen as a possible spammer or new account.

Anyone got any ideas how I can post stuff on tumblr and have the post appear in search results. Not appearing in search results is like face book with out friend requests.

A rough idea on a time period, number of likes, follows or posts/reblogs before my posts appear in search results.

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsSmB.png

Comment: Are you performing the search via the dashboard, or your own site? If the later, I believe this is a known issue / quirk. If you untag and then tag the post again, it should display in the search results.

Comment: No through tumblr dash/search.

Comment: Do you have a link to the post and the search?

Comment: Not really since I deleted most of m posts. But thanks for the help. It's all fixed.

Comment: Funny thing, the fact you can't find your posts back through any kind of search mechanism unless your posts are tagged mean that a huge portion of Tumblr is deep web.

Answer (score 1):

It is now solved.

It appears to be that you need to follow about 100 blogs and/or like 100 posts and/or post nearly 200 times.

I just went and followed random blogs, liked random posts and essential posted gibberish. And when I got to around the numbers I just mentioned I was able to see my posts in the search results.

Then I unfollowed, unlinked and deleted my posts.